# Validate an e-mail item with an e-mail list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form that collects e-mail adresses. The item is created by Form settings. I wanted to add an email validation using a list of e-mail in my possession.

Here the code I wrote:

```
function onOpen() {
 var items = FormApp.getItems();
 var emailItem = items[0];

 var pattern = "email@gmail.com|another-email@gmail.com";

 var emailValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText('Inserisci il tuo indirizzo e-mail corretto.')
  .requireTextMatchesPattern(pattern)
  .build();
 emailItem.setValidation(emailValidation);
}
```

I'm quite new to GAS and I am struggling with reference pages.. Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Forms built-in feature to collect email addresses doesn't support databa validation. Instead you have to use a short text question.

Comment: Thank you Rubén! So, if I want something that works similar to the quiz feature (automatic sending of the results by email) I have to code it by myself. Am I right?